# Opensource Code Example - Django, Backbone.js (and Coffeescript)

Tags: django, backbone.js, open-source

Are there any open source projects or examples using **both** django and backbone.js?

I learn best from looking at actual code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to ask more specific questions. You can read more about what questions are best for StackOverflow at FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Thanks! I especially liked the part where you took the time to be helpful rather than condescending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here are some good examples made for django users:

1. http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2012/jun/5/backbonejs-django-developers/
2. http://joshbohde.com/blog/backbonejs-and-django
3. https://github.com/joshbohde/django-backbone-example
4. http://lanyrd.com/2011/pycodeconf/sghxt/ (this is a presentation by leah culver)

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks! I especially liked the part where you took the time to be helpful rather than condescending. (In this case, very helpful... I thank you and many others who stumble upon this in the future thank you.)